# On a conceptual question on Theory of Equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

We have two equations:
$$x^2+y^2=12\tag1$$
$$x^2+y^2-6x-2\sqrt3y=0\tag2$$
From these two equations we get a third equation
$$12-6x-2\sqrt3y=0\tag3$$
Thus
$$x=\frac{12-2\sqrt3y}6  ---(*) $$
Now $x$ is a root for $(3)$. Why isn't it for $(2)$ as well?

Reasoning:
In $(1)$, $x^2+y^2=12$ so basically $(3)$ is $(2)$ with the value of $x^2+y^2$ substituted.

What I tried doing: When I actually put $x$ from $(3)$ in equation $(1,2)$ i actually get the same quadratic $y^2-\sqrt3y-6=0$

Note: I am currently comfortable with algebra-precalculus and single variable calculus.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "Now $x$ is a root for equation 3"? This phrase doesn't make much sense: $x$ here is still $x$, the original variable; since you haven't found a value for it, what root are you talking about?

Comment: Overly short answer: because the thread of logic goes  *forwards*, not *backwards*. A solution to (1) and (2) must satisfy (3). The reasoning doesn't go the other way around.

Comment: @Hurkyl could you elaborate what you said. The solution of this system of equation satisfies all three equations. So shouldnt the root of Eqn 2 and Eqn 3 be same ?

Comment: @user33699: The point is that you haven't shown it is a solution to this system! You've merely shown that anything that is a solution to the system of equations will additionally satisfy (*).

Comment: (p.s. use `\qquad` to insert a lot of blank space in math mode. e.g. `a \qquad b` gives $a \qquad b$. It can be used multiple times if needed)

Comment: @zipirovich i meant that when x satisfies the condition (*) it will be a "solution" for Equation 3.

Comment: @Hurkyl I havnt solved the system of equations to keep the post short.

Comment: @ziprovich when x satisfies the condition (*) then it would be a solution to Equation 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might note that geometrically, (1) and (2) are equations of circles.  The two circles intersect at two points.  Equation (3) represents a straight line that passes through both points.  But those are the only points where the line intersects either circle.

[image]